# How to define range of IP numbers to a variable

Tags: php, ip, preg-match

I want to set a range of IP numbers to a name in php

How can I write below line in correct way in PHP?

```
$block_renge = array("192.168.*.*", "10.10.*.*");
```

i want * to be any number (0-255) . could someone please help me the way i could do this

Then I check the IP with below code:

```
if ( ( in_array( $ip_address, $block_renge ) ) ) {
// do some stuff
//$ip_address is the customer ip address
```

maybe with preg_match we could done this?

Comment: It depends how the values are being used.

Comment: post edited. check again plz.

Comment: What is `$ip_address`? It looks like you had previously written regex. `in_array` doesnt work with regexs.

Comment: I would suggest to avoid storing all possible IPs in an array unless you have a restricted arbitrary list of those.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) and [`long2ip()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php):

```
function ip_range($from, $to) {
  $start = ip2long($from);
  $end = ip2long($to);
  $range = range($start, $end);
  return array_map('long2ip', $range);
}
```

The above turns the two IP addresses into numbers (using PHP core functions), creates a range of numbers and then turns that number range into IP addresses.

If you want them separated by spaces just `implode()` the result.

You can then use

```
if (in_array($ip, $ip_range)){ //...
```

Comment: thank you . but i looking for way to do it with preg_match

Comment: @Mostafa ... things that should have been posted in the question